# Slack API sandbox or demo-data?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I'm building a web-app that runs analysis on Slack activity and I need test data. Do not know where to turn to, doesn't have to be millions of messages, but need data for the following:

- user status (online/away/logged off) changes
- messages sent (date, user, contents)
- reactions (date, type, reaction on what message)
- huddles, voice/video chats with metadata

any help is much appreciated

Comment: If you have access to a slack instance with admin access, you can get the sample data via an export - all in json format which you can parse into db. export includes.  Check out https://slack.com/intl/en-in/help/articles/201658943-Export-your-workspace-data

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but I do not have access to a slack instance other than my dev one...

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing an app to be used on the Enterprise Grid plan, you can request a sandbox from Slack directly, though it won't contain any test data off the bat.

More information on that here: https://api.slack.com/enterprise/grid/testing.

That being said, you could populate it with information yourself, using a combination of several different Web API methods.  Here are a couple methods that may be of use to you:

1. [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) - posts a message in a channel
2. [`conversations.create`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.create) - creates a new channel
3. [`reactions.add`](https://api.slack.com/methods/reactions.add) - adds a reaction onto an item